# arcpy.da.UpdateCursor gives SyntaxError?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, syntaxerror

I'm trying to use Python to:

1. Do a union between 2 layers (LandTrust and Precincts) - this works
2. Create a field called "Overlap - this works
3. Create a da.UpdateCursor to populate the fields with values - this does Not work

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong (I'm using both the Python Window and an independent text editor).

Here is my code:

```
>>> import arcpy
... unionLayer = arcpy.Union_analysis(["LandTrust", "Precincts"], "UnionOutput", "ALL")
... arcpy.AddField_management(unionLayer, "Overlap", "TEXT", "", "", 20, "", "NULLABLE")
... updateRows = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(unionLayer, ["FID_LandTrust", "FID_Precincts", "Overlap"])
... for row in updateRows:
...     if (row[0] != -1 and row[1] = -1):
...         row[2] = "LandTr"
...     elif (row[0] = -1 and row[1] != -1):
...         row[2] = "Pre"
...     elif (row[0] != -1 and row[1] != -1):
...         row[2] = "Overlap"
...     updateRows.updateRow(row)
... del updateRows
... del row

Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 6)
>>>
```

It seems that my `if` statement is the issue. I'm executing the code by pressing enter twice at the end.

Comment: Assignment (`=`) versus equivalence (`==`) on line 6 (and 8). In the future, use the `with` syntax to eliminate the need to `del`

Comment: When presenting code here please always leave out the Python window prompts (like I have in my answer).  That way its easy for potential answerers to copy/paste your code for testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented by @Vince:

> Assignment (`=`) versus equivalence (`==`) on line 6 (and 8). In the
>   future, use the `with` syntax to eliminate the need to `del`

Try this instead:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.Union_analysis(["LandTrust", "Precincts"], "UnionOutput", "ALL")
arcpy.AddField_management("UnionOutput", "Overlap", "TEXT", "", "", 20, "", "NULLABLE")
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("UnionOutput", ["FID_LandTrust", "FID_Precincts", "Overlap"]) as "UnionOutput" as updateRows:
    for row in updateRows:
        if (row[0] != -1 and row[1] == -1):
            row[2] = "LandTr"
        elif (row[0] == -1 and row[1] != -1):
            row[2] = "Pre"
        elif (row[0] != -1 and row[1] != -1):
            row[2] = "Overlap"
        updateRows.updateRow(row)
```